# VueJs Dynamic template rendering

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

It is a well-known problem, when you append the HTML to the DOM, containing the other vue components, there is the option only to insert them as an HTML, also it is possible to render components in the html. But I can't find the solution to attach it to the same parent, it behaves as a separate instance.

I have created an example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="clicked">
      Load greeting
  </button>
  <div id="inserted" v-html="internalHtml"></div>

  <!-- <greeting @clicked="greetingClicked"></greeting> -->
</div>

const Greeting = Vue.component('greeting', {
  template: '<p>Hi, dude! <br/><button @click="clicked">Click me!</button> </p>', 
  methods: {
    clicked() {
        this.$emit('clicked');
    }
  }
});

const LoadedHtml = 'This is a greating: <greeting @clicked="greetingClicked"></greeting>';

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
            internalHtml: ''    
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clicked() {
         this.internalHtml = LoadedHtml;
       this.$nextTick(function(){
            new Vue({el: '#inserted'} );
       });
    },
    greetingClicked() {
        alert('Boo!');
    }
  }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/relaximus/znh3svy7/29/

The alert 'boo!' must appear after clicking 'click me'.
I would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this through dynamic components: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Using your example: https://jsfiddle.net/dqws96mr/1/

```js
const Greeting = Vue.component('greeting', {
  template: '<p>Hi, dude! <br/><button @click="clicked">Click me!</button> </p>', 
  methods: {
    clicked() {
        this.$emit('clicked');
    }
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
            myDynamicComponent: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clicked() {
         this.myDynamicComponent = 'greeting'
    },
    greetingClicked() {
        alert('Boo!');
    }
  }
});
```